# insert multiple row to db in same time with multi_query

Tags: php, mysql

I have to insert 2 queries and I want run them with multi_queries. In every run of the file there should be 2 row added to the table but my problem is that they don't get inserted. My connection to the db is ok and I tested the queries with that

```
    $q1 ="INSERT INTO auto_charge(phone,charged_at,created_at,updated_at) VALUES ('123456789','2018-01-24 12:37:07','2018-01-27 09:19:42','2018-01-27 09:19:42')";
    $q1 .="INSERT INTO auto_charge(phone,charged_at,created_at,updated_at) VALUES ('987654321','2018-01-24 12:37:07','2018-01-27 09:19:42','2018-01-27 09:19:42')";
    $result = $conn->multi_query( $q1 );
```

Comment: you have to put semicolon(:) end of every query and last query semicolon is optional

Comment: @AmitGaud didn't work

Comment: what's error you getting?@sina

Comment: @AmitGaud no error

Comment: then please share table schema and also complete php code?@sina

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are **inserting** into a **single table**, you can write your query like this

```
$query = "INSERT INTO auto_charge(phone,charged_at,created_at,updated_at)
VALUES
('123456789','2018-01-24 12:37:07','2018-01-27 09:19:42','2018-01-27 09:19:42'),
('987654321','2018-01-24 12:37:07','2018-01-27 09:19:42','2018-01-27 09:19:42');";

$result = $conn->query($query )
```

Or, if you are **inserting** into **multiple tables**, you can write like this

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO auto_charge(phone,charged_at,created_at,updated_at) VALUES ('123456789','2018-01-24 12:37:07','2018-01-27 09:19:42','2018-01-27 09:19:42');";
$sql .= "INSERT INTO auto_charge(phone,charged_at,created_at,updated_at) VALUES ('987654321','2018-01-24 12:37:07','2018-01-27 09:19:42','2018-01-27 09:19:42');";

$result = $conn->multi_query($sql)
```

**Note:** Each SQL statement must be separated by a semicolon.

Comment: i have to run queries in that way

Comment: Please don't use blockquote for text. I edited this one and another of your answers. This has been discussed on meta.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner thanks, i just used it to make a note. I will check on meta to use blockquotes

Answer (score 3):

try array to store data. then take the count of the array and run the loop depend on array count. execute the query inside the loop. give me full detail i ll explain clearly. thnank you

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong you can insert multiple values within single insert query like the code below

```
Insert into TableName(Column1Name, Column2Name) Values
                 (Value1, Value2),
                 (Value3, Value4),
                 and so on... ;
```

**I hope this will help you.**

Comment: i don't\ have values in same place it is for test and i want to run 2 queries in this way

Comment: Then why are you running two queries at same place.if it is necessary then why don't you get values at same place.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "dbname");

  $query ="INSERT INTO auto_charge(phone,charged_at,created_at,updated_at) VALUES ('123456789','2018-01-24 12:37:07','2018-01-27 09:19:42','2018-01-27 09:19:42')";
  $query .="INSERT INTO auto_charge(phone,charged_at,created_at,updated_at) VALUES ('987654321','2018-01-24 12:37:07','2018-01-27 09:19:42','2018-01-27 09:19:42')";

/* execute multi query */
     mysqli_multi_query($link, $query);

?>
```

Try This.